# How to repair documents that display the “The document xxx.pages could not be opened” error when opened in Pages?

Tags: macos, pages

I recently did a clean Mountain Lion install, after which I restored some important Pages documents from a backup HD.

Now, when I try to open these documents in Pages, I get the following error:

[image: The document “xxx.pages” could not be opened.]

Someone in [this old thread on the Apple support forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/245499) suggested to use Disk Utility to repair disk permissions, as well as the disk itself, but that doesn’t seem to help.

The weird thing is I can still open these documents using my girlfriend’s laptop just fine. I tried opening the file on her Mac, saving it, then transferring it back to my laptop, but no luck — it still shows the error message.

Any other ideas as to how these documents can be repaired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up buying and installing Pages from the App Store; I was using an old iWork copy before. Sucks that I bought the same product twice now, but at least I could open my files after that.